# Displaying a ProgressRing while Connecting

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In my program I have a timer that when it ticks to 0 I want my app to "connect" to a service and while it's "connecting", have it display a progress ring.

It would seem as if my progress ring does not become "activated" until the end of the function in which it's being set to active. But since I am awaiting the completion of the Connect function, the progress ring never shows up.

I've tried a variety of different methods to solve this, but I lack the understanding regarding awaits/tasks/Dispatching to make this work.

Here is the code pertaining to the ProgressRing and the Connect function:

```
vm.IsConnecting = true;

await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => vm.Connect());

if (vm.ConnectionClear)
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), vm);

vm.IsConnecting = false;
```

vm.IsConnecting is what the IsActive property of the ProgressRing is bound to.

How can I make it display the progressRing immediately after vm.IsConnecting is set to true?

It should be noted that I am targeting WinRT, and thus my toolbox is somewhat limited.

The weird thing about this is that I have the same exact block of code as above in the EventHandler for a button click, and it works like I think it should. That is, when the button is clicked, the ProgressRing is displayed, and the program will do the connect method and when it's complete, the ProgressRing will disappear.

```
private async void Connect_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vm.IsConnecting = true;

    await Window.Current.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => vm.Connect());

    if (vm.ConnectionClear)
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), vm);

    vm.IsConnecting = false;
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at BackgroundWorker? I believe it is specifically designed to allow background processes to work with the UI thread and report their progress using their own methods. Dont think this exactly answer so i didn't write it out as an answer but good reference for later maybe? Have a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I desperately wanted to use BackgroundWorkers since I've used them previously and have a stronger knowledge of how they function. That being said, they are not included with the WinRT toolset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is to expose an `async` method on your VM, as such:

```
public async Task ConnectAsync();
```

which you can then use like this:

```
vm.IsConnecting = true;

await vm.ConnectAsync();

if (vm.ConnectionClear)
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), vm);

vm.IsConnecting = false;
```

As a general rule, any use of `Dispatcher` is a sign that your design needs work.

Comment: I can remove the dispatcher snippet using your method, but it still refuses to display the progress ring when I think it should be displayed. I made an edit to the original post that may or may not provide some more insight into my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Is your `ConnectAsync` method properly asynchronous?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that question. Connect was public void Connect() and is now public async Task ConnectAsync(). I'm assuming there's more I need to change, yet I don't want to await anything within the Connect method.

Comment: Whatever your "service" is (HTTP/WCF/whatever), change that to use the asynchronous methods and `await` that from within `ConnectAsync`. If you just make `ConnectAsync` `async` without actually using `await` then it will not work properly; as the compiler error states, it will run synchronously, thus defeating the purpose of the spinner.

Comment: It works! The sigh of relief when that progress ring finally popped up registered on the Richter scale. Thanks so much!